# Inno Setup Get Current .BIN file during Installation

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Get the current .BIN file copying during installation?

setup.exe
setup-1.bin
setup-2.bin

Message like "working setup-2.bin"

Comment: Your question is really unclear. What are you trrying to achieve? All .bin files must be in the same folder as .exe file.

Comment: @Slappy - User wants to display (as a `TLabel` od `TNewStaticText`) the `Current` BIN, that Installer is unpacking from at the very moment. Similar to `WizardForm.FilenameLabel` which displays `Current` FILE.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, that is really tricky. There is no public interface for this.

Inno of course knows which file is stored in which .bin file but this information is not available for you (it is internal).

So the only way is to modify Inno's sources.